# Javascript multiple outcomes

Tags: javascript

I can wrap my head around much more intricate code but this has me hung up.

I have two page types: browse:category, browse:search and browse:search having id = 0 and not = 0.

For browse:category, I need to return page 1
For browse:search where id!= 0 return page 2
For browse:search where id = 0 return page 3

How close did I get?

```
if (page=='browse:category'){
    addPlacementType('page1');
}
elseif (id != 0'){
    addPlacementType('page2');
}
else (id == 0'){
    addPlacementType('page3');
}
```

Comment: first remove those accidental quotations you got next to the 0s

Comment: also change `elseif` to `else if`, then either change the last `else` to `else if` or remove the `(id == 0')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
if (page == 'browse:category'){
    addPlacementType('page1');
} else if (page === 'browse:search' && id != '0'){
    addPlacementType('page2');
} else if (page === 'browse:search' && id == '0'){
    addPlacementType('page3');
}
```

There are problems with your syntax, there's no `elseif` operator but you can use `else if` instead (which actually is not a distinct operator).

You also have a missing quote. Comparing the `id` with string is not a big deal - JavaScript implicitly will cast the `id` to string when you use `==` (i.e. `'1' == 1`).

Answer (score 0):

#### There are at least two problems, and one missing piece.

1. There is a single-quote missing in two places, or there ought to be no single-quotes at all.
2. You also have an `else` in use that ought to be `else if`.
3. You are missing the `browse:search` criteria check.

If `id` is a string, use this:

```
if ( page == 'browse:category' ){
    addPlacementType( 'page1' );
}
else if ( id != '0' ){
    addPlacementType( 'page2' );
}
else if ( id == '0' ){
    addPlacementType( 'page3' );
}
```

Or if `id` is an integer:

```
if ( page == 'browse:category' ){
    addPlacementType( 'page1' );
}
else if ( id != 0 ){
    addPlacementType( 'page2' );
}
else if ( id == 0 ){
    addPlacementType('page3' );
}
```

To include the `page === 'browse:search'` piece, do this ( if `id` is a string ):

```
if ( page == 'browse:category' ){
    addPlacementType('page1');
} else if ( page == 'browse:search' ){
    if ( id != '0' ) addPlacementType( 'page2' );
    else if ( id == '0') addPlacementType( 'page3' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, get rid of those quation marks next to the 0. Second, if and elseif have a condition next to them, but else DOES NOT, so either you put elseif instead of else then end it, or you leave else as it is and it executes the third instruction whatever id is equal to, besides the first two conditions, of course.